# Moment Generating Function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find the probability $P(X > 1.5)$ if $X$ has moment-generating function:
$$
M_X(t) = \frac{1}{1-t/2} \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3}e^t\right)^4.
$$
I've tried couple times, but I'm not getting the answer the teacher gave us.

Answer (score 3):

Outline: This solution depends on mgf recognition. The $\frac{1}{1-t/2}$ is the mgf of a random variable $S$ which is exponential parameter $\lambda=2$. The $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}e^t$ is the mgf of a Bernoulli, probability of success $p$. Thus $\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}e^t\right)^4$ is the mgf of a binomial $T$, $n=4$, $p=2/3$.

So our given mgf is the mgf of $S+T$, where $S$ and $T$ are independent.

It should not be hard to find the probability that $S+T\le 1.5$. There are two cases to consider, $T=0$ and $T=1$.